# Firebase method doesn't work

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to save date by using this method because I want to get id of object after saved , and use it to save image joining with this object , but this method doesn't work and how do I get the object id?

```
    postRef.setValue("I'm writing data", withCompletionBlock: {
        (error, ref) in
        if (error != nil) {
            Constant.displayAlert(view: self, title:"", Message: "RRRR")
        } else {
            Constant.displayAlert(view: self, title:"", Message: "RRRR")
        }
    })
```

Comment: What object Id? Are you not able to set the value to your DB? Also elaborate your question further with more info

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, you're saving your data as the postRef's immediate child and you'll end up overwriting all the data at the location of postRef.

Although you've left out a lot of details, in my understanding you could use the following:

```
insertionRef = postRef.childByAutoId() // inserts a child by an auto generated Id
requiredId = insertionRef.key // returns a string
insertionRef.setValue("I'm writing data", withCompletionBlock: {
    (error, ref) in
    if (error != nil) {
        Constant.displayAlert(view: self, title:"", Message: "RRRR")
    } else {
        Constant.displayAlert(view: self, title:"", Message: "RRRR")
    }
})
```

In my opinion, **requiredId** is the Id that you're looking for and your data will be stored at the path specified in **postRef**.

Hope this helps.